# What does "System Load" represent when SSH into an ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

When I SSH into my ubuntu server the following message is displayed:

```
  System load:  12.44              Processes:           131
  Usage of /:   13.5% of 58.93GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 55%                IP address for eth0: 107.170.34.40
  Swap usage:   0%
```

What does a system load of `12.44` indicate? Is that 12.44% of resources being used? Is 12.44 high/low? Appreciate any answers.

Comment: Probably a snapshot of CPU usage... Use the "top" command to get more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer: Load tells you how many processes are waiting for their turn in a set interval. The usual intervals are 1, 5 and 15 minutes, and I suspect that the value shown is for the 1 minute interval. For example, a load of 12.44 is high for a single-core system, but normal for a 12-core system. If your server has a 4-core CPU, it would be overloaded by roughly 200% (so a load of 300%). If it's a 2x12-core server, it's on a 50% load, 50% idle.

For more details, see the Wikipedia article on [Load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 1):

It is the number of processes that are either in a runnable or uninterruptable state, that is the processes which are running or want to run. (it's the info you get under "load average" in tools like uptime or top)

The data comes out of the program **landscape-sysinfo**

12.44 is a pretty high load!